# DevStack/OpenStack: How do I create a tenant?

Tags: openstack

Ubuntu Server 14.04. Installed the latest DevStack. At the end of the installation it gave me admin & demo user/passwords and an auth URL. My intention is to create a tenant and a user. Here is what I do.

```
$: cat env.sh
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://10.0.3.15:5000/v2.0
export OS_USERNAME=admin
export OS_PASSWORD=8adb0ddg3b6ef3dc78ac
$:
$: source env.sh
$:
$: keystone tenant-list
+----------------------------------+-------+---------+
|                id                |  name | enabled |
+----------------------------------+-------+---------+
| 7920e943bd1742e198ea78f8453534d5 | admin |   True  |
| 435d9b5ce34f430ea50e4643d33230e7 |  demo |   True  |
+----------------------------------+-------+---------+
$: keystone tenant-create --name=ten1

$: keystone tenant-list
+----------------------------------+-------+---------+
|                id                |  name | enabled |
+----------------------------------+-------+---------+
| 7920e943bd1742e198ea78f8453534d5 | admin |   True  |
| 435d9b5ce34f430ea50e4643d33230e7 |  demo |   True  |
+----------------------------------+-------+---------+
$:
```

Why does tenant-list display user list? Why doesn't tenant-create say anything?
Am I missing any basic concepts?

Answer (score 3):

In DevStack, the starter user names match the project/tenant user names. You can create more users with different tenant names using the docs such as http://docs.openstack.org/icehouse/install-guide/install/apt/content/keystone-users.html.

I think what you're missing is linking a user to the tenant with:

```
$ keystone user-create --name=fred --pass=SOME_PASS --email=SOME_EMAIL
$ keystone user-role-add --user=fred --role=_member_ --tenant=ten1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute stack.sh in devstack, it creates various tenants for you like admin,demo,service etc. Along with tenants, it creates users like admin,demo and service users.
With the pre-req data, once can try out admin operations and member operations.

if you wish you to have your own user and tenant , you can execute the below after sourcing openrc/env

```
//Create a tenant
keystone tenant-create --name <tenantName>

//Create a User in a tenant
keystone user-create --name <username> --pass <password> --tenant <tenantName>

//Assign a role for a user for a specific tenant
keystone user-role-add --user <username> --tenant <tenantName> --role <roleName>
```